# Rename filenames and remove N number of characters

Tags: rename

I need help to rename my files and remove some characters.

Original files

```
X103032720-20230630-WE02A-3.txt
X203032720-20230630-RT02B-2.txt
X503032720-20230630-XC02A-1.txt
```

I want to remove the 3rd dash-delimited part of the filename (X103032720-20230630**-WE02A**-3.txt) to get below output

```
X103032720-20230630-3.txt
X203032720-20230630-2.txt
X503032720-20230630-1.txt
```

Thanks!

I have tried below bash script but it will delete last 12 characters

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in X*-*-*-*.txt

do
   mv "$file" "${file%????????????}".txt

done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split on the dash.

```
$: printf "%s\n" *.txt
X103032720-20230630-WE02A-3.txt
X203032720-20230630-RT02B-2.txt
X503032720-20230630-XC02A-1.txt

$: while IFS=- read a b x c; do cp "$a-$b-$x-$c" "$a-$b-$c"; done < <( printf "%s\n" *.txt )

$: printf "%s\n" *.txt
X103032720-20230630-3.txt
X103032720-20230630-WE02A-3.txt
X203032720-20230630-2.txt
X203032720-20230630-RT02B-2.txt
X503032720-20230630-1.txt
X503032720-20230630-XC02A-1.txt
```

Probably faster to just reconstruct with basic [parameter parsing](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) though.

```
$: printf "%s\n" *.txt
X103032720-20230630-WE02A-3.txt
X203032720-20230630-RT02B-2.txt
X503032720-20230630-XC02A-1.txt

$: for f in *.txt; do end=${f##*-}; base=${f%-*}; cp "$f" "${base%-*}-$end"; done

$: printf "%s\n" *.txt
X103032720-20230630-3.txt
X103032720-20230630-WE02A-3.txt
X203032720-20230630-2.txt
X203032720-20230630-RT02B-2.txt
X503032720-20230630-1.txt
X503032720-20230630-XC02A-1.txt
```

## addendum

> i forgot to mention that there are also files like X103032720-20230630-WE02A.txt X203032720-20230630-RT02B.txt X503032720-20230630-XC02A.txt

Well, that's not gonna work...
Are the first two fields fixed width? If so, we can use that.

```
$: printf "%s\n" *.txt
X103032720-20230630-WE02A-3.txt
X103032720-20230630-WE02A.txt
X203032720-20230630-RT02B-2.txt
X203032720-20230630-RT02B.txt
X503032720-20230630-XC02A-1.txt
X503032720-20230630-XC02A.txt

$: for f in *.txt
do end="${f##X?????????-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]}"; 
   base="${f%$end}";
   end="${end#-[^-.][^-.][^-.][^-.][^-.]}"; 
   mv "$f" "$base$end";
done

$: printf "%s\n" *.txt
X103032720-20230630-3.txt
X103032720-20230630.txt
X203032720-20230630-2.txt
X203032720-20230630.txt
X503032720-20230630-1.txt
X503032720-20230630.txt
```

The slowest part of this is the actual `mv`.

Comment: This worked - for f in *.txt; do end=${f##*-}; base=${f%-*}; cp "$f" "${base%-*}-$end"; done

Comment: But i forgot to mention that there are also files like X103032720-20230630-WE02A.txt
X203032720-20230630-RT02B.txt
X503032720-20230630-XC02A.txt and once i run your script,, i get output as below  X103032720-20230630-3.txt
X203032720-20230630-2.txt
X503032720-20230630-1.txt
X103032720-WE02A.txt
X203032720-RT02B.txt
X503032720-XC02A.txt  it is correct for those with -1,-2,-3 in filenames but incorrect to those without,,i need the dates retained and not the 3rd column. please help, thanks a lot